# How to convert char pointer returned from a function to string?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers

I am playing around with socket programming on Qt. I am reading char array from server socket as client socket and returning the result as char pointer.

```
char* zgr_socket::sendMessage(){
    char buffer[5];
        while(1){
            bzero(buffer,2);
            n = read(sockfd,buffer,2);
            if (n < 0){  }

            close(sockfd);
            return buffer;
        }
}
```

And I am trying to get the resulting char array from in this method

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    char* returnedChar = mySocket->sendMessage();


    std::string aString(returnedChar);
    QString myQString = QString::fromStdString(aString);

    ui->label1->setText(myQString);
}
```

No matter what I've tried I couldn't manage to get the correct char array. When I debug an look at `return buffer` line it returns correct array, but after some kind of magic I get arbitrary values in `aString` variable. Can anybody see the reason, please?

Comment: @AndyG That frickng buffer is a local variable and the return value a dangling ponter

Comment: @DieterLücking This comment is the correct answer and made me laugh, as well. Thank you.

Comment: Doing socket programming while using purely C apis is a surefire way of hurting yourself badly. I assume that you're doing it for some specific reason, because if all you wish is to push some data over the network, Qt provides all this in an easy to use fashion. The whole point of Qt is to make your life easier. At least try to use C++ containers to move your data around, such as a `QByteArray` or `std::vector<char>`. That way you're less likely to die a violent C death, and you won't be dealing with completely unnecessary manual memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a pointer to `char buffer[5];` except that buffer is a local variable of the function, therefore after the function exits it ceases to exist. You now have a dangling pointer. Try returning a `string` from the function instead of a `char*` and just create the string as a part of the return statement.

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. I will accep the answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

There is a QString constructor which takes char pointer as parameter:

```
QString::QString(const char * str)
```

[see more](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8)